# How do I get if static window is clicked

Tags: winapi

I have a static Window in my C++ program, but it doesn't respond when I click on it. Code I use to create control:

```
 hButton = CreateWindowEx(0, "static",NULL,
      WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP,
      10, 5, 200, 40,
      hwnd, (HMENU) ID_hButton, hInstance, NULL);
```

It wont show the MessageBox when I click it.

```
 case WM_COMMAND:{
      switch(wParam){
           case ID_hButton:
                MessageBox(0,"","",0);
                break;
           }
      }
      break;
 }
```

So is there something wrong here or is it my App?

**Now I have a new problem:** when I click the static control it does not show the MessageBox until I press `Alt`. Anyone want to refer on why that is happening?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by adding the SS_NOTIFY Style to it after I read a former post. ty